# Sorting multiple csv files in folder using powershell

Tags: powershell, columnsorting

I have af bunch of csv files (1000+) in a folder.
every csv's have a column that need to be sortet desc.

With my low powershell skills im only abel to do import one file at the time.

"Part of the code":

```
$csv = Import-Csv $fileA -Encoding "default"  | Sort-Object -Property {$_.PrD -as [decimal]}
```

how do i make this part of the sorting work into multiply files?
The sortig column name is PrD. and scaling between 1 and 99.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$csvFiles = "path-to-csv-files"
Get-ChildItem -Path $csvFiles | ForEach-Object { Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName -Encoding "default" | Sort-Object -Property { $_.PrD -as [decimal] } -Descending }
```

Comment: I think you should move the sort outside the ForEach block to the end

Comment: i had try using get-childitem ....
But i think it sees my csv files 13 columns as 1 column.
if i use format-tabel.

is it because my csv files using Semicolon insted of comma's ?